# TFS 2012 fresh install on fresh Windows Server 2008 warning that reporting services are not installed

Tags: team-foundation-server

I am attempting to evaluate TFS 2012 for our organization but cannot seem to get past the first step of configuring the server using the "Standard Single Server" configuration wizard. In particular, in the service account selection screen, I am warned that:

> Reporting services are not installed on this computer. You need to install Reporting Services to complete TFS installation with this wizard.

This is disheartening because the way I understand it, this should have been installed with the default TFS installation (in fact, no installation options are even provided) and this is a fresh and up-to-date Windows Server 2008 VM.

I know I could install SQL Server 2008 or 2012 from MSDN, but shouldn't this work "out of the box?" I'd really rather use the default, small, integrated version of SQL Server that comes with TFS 2012 rather than rolling my own.

If it matters, this server is joined to a domain and I am running TFS installation wizard as a domain administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS Express\Basic comes with SQL Express. The standard edition doesn't and you must have it pre-installed.

[**MSDN: SQL Server Requirements for Team Foundation Server**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd631889.aspx)

Comment: My confusion was that I thought the (smaller) Express edition would bet the one w/o SQL Express and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

As KMoraz indicated you can use the Basic configuration to setup your server. Another option when you are evaluating the software it to sign up for a free account for the [Team Foundation Service](https://tfs.visualstudio.com)